# Laravel 7 I cannot display my images on remote server but can locally

Tags: laravel, permissions

I use a shared hosting and after pushing my site on it everything works fine except the fact that my images are not displayed. I must add that this works smoothly on the local laravel embedded server.
Let's take example of the banner images ( a carrousel)

First the filesystem configuration file

```
<?php
return [
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            /*added */
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0664,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0775,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
            ],
            /*end added*/
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

As the image files come from an other app (symfony) on the same shared hosting I copied the files by command line into /storage/app/public/banner directory and not seeing them also into /public/storage/banner directory

Here is my view

```
 <div id="option" class="carousel carousel-fade container banner" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly"
      class="carousel slide"
      data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo asset('storage/banner/banner-001.jpg'); ?>" alt="First slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-002.jpg"  alt="Second slide"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-003.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-004.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-005.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-006.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="/storage/banner/banner-007.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php echo asset('storage/banner/banner-001.jpg'); ?>
```

I tried writing the url directly or using the asset helper but I dont'see any difference.

To be comprehensive hereafter are the permissions of files and folders

```
denentza@fox [~/laravel.denentzat.fr]# ls -l public/storage
total 16
drwxr-x--- 4 denentza denentza 4096 14 sept. 07:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 denentza nobody   4096 14 sept. 07:39 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 denentza denentza 4096 14 sept. 07:08 banner/
drwxr-x--- 3 denentza denentza 4096 13 sept. 18:03 photos/

denentza@fox [~/laravel.denentzat.fr]# ls -l public/storage/banner
total 632
drwxrwxr-x 2 denentza denentza   4096 14 sept. 07:08 ./
drwxr-x--- 4 denentza denentza   4096 14 sept. 07:16 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  68243 14 sept. 07:08 banner-001.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 106837 14 sept. 07:08 banner-002.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 121547 14 sept. 07:08 banner-003.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  55213 14 sept. 07:08 banner-004.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  78082 14 sept. 07:08 banner-005.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  84133 14 sept. 07:08 banner-006.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 110553 14 sept. 07:08 banner-007.jpg

denentza@fox [~/laravel.denentzat.fr]# ls -l storage/app/public
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 denentza denentza 4096 14 sept. 08:03 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 denentza denentza 4096 13 sept. 17:16 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 denentza denentza 4096 14 sept. 08:03 banner/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 denentza denentza   14 13 sept. 16:22 .gitignore*

denentza@fox [~/laravel.denentzat.fr]# ls -l public/storage/banner
total 632
drwxrwxr-x 2 denentza denentza   4096 14 sept. 07:08 ./
drwxr-x--- 4 denentza denentza   4096 14 sept. 07:16 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  68243 14 sept. 07:08 banner-001.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 106837 14 sept. 07:08 banner-002.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 121547 14 sept. 07:08 banner-003.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  55213 14 sept. 07:08 banner-004.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  78082 14 sept. 07:08 banner-005.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza  84133 14 sept. 07:08 banner-006.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 denentza denentza 110553 14 sept. 07:08 banner-007.jpg
```

Comment: Do you already check with laravel file system? Here link:   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel FileSystem. The Laravel Flysystem integration provides simple to use drivers for working with local filesystems and Amazon S3. Even better, it's amazingly simple to switch between these storage options as the API remains the same for each system.

Here is official: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Here is sample: https://www.larashout.com/a-complete-guide-to-laravel-storage

Comment: Thanks for your time. I thought I was using the Laravel Filesystem ! Please see my config/filesystem.php above. But would that mean I cannot put images manually (I mean by other mean than uploading them by the app) into the folders ?

Comment: You can get Image by `Storage::disk('s3')->get('image.jpg');`

Comment: It seems I have trouble making you understanding my true point. Apart from a probable misuse I made of the Laravel filesystem, misuse we will admit fixed, my question is how to reproduce on the server side a directory of images with numerous levels of nested subdirectories and making all this stuff displayable in the pages. Can I do that using a standard file manager (what I call "manually" ) or should I write views and controller to do it.